# How to find a point in a Right Triangle given 2 known points, all sides, all interior angles

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry, triangles

This triangle is not parallel or vertical, it's in a 2d plane. Distance formula gave me very troubling results, looking to use SOH CAH TOA, particularly a simple method and not a complex method of solving.

[image: diagram]

Comment: There is a problem here. A $30°-60°-90°$ triangle is half of an equilateral triangle, so the short side should be exactly half the hypotenuse. (In your diagram, adding a mirror image on the left side should make an equilateral triangle.) But $25$ is not close to half of $132.52$.

Comment: @Théophile I got $10.83^\circ$ for the measure of $\angle BAC$, with the letters as defined in my answer. The diagram is indeed inaccurate.

Comment: that's right, it is inaccurate, can i go back and re-do this please? i want it as a 30-60-90

Comment: @Théophile fixed :D

Answer (score 4):

Define
$$A=\langle11444,1701\rangle$$
$$B=\langle11406,1576\rangle$$
$$\implies A-B=\langle38,125\rangle$$Rotate this $90^\circ$ to get $\langle125,-38\rangle$. Add this to $B$, adjusting for length, to get $C$.
$$C = \frac{25}{\sqrt{17069}}\langle125,-38\rangle + B$$
And simplify.

Some explanation:
$A-B$ will give you the point $A$ would be at if $B$ was the origin. Drawing a few points on the coordinate plane and rotating them will show you why $\langle x,y\rangle \to \langle y,-x\rangle$ rotates a point $90^\circ$ clockwise. $\langle 125,-38\rangle$ has magnitude ~$131$, which when divided by ~$131$ gives $1$, and which multiplied by $25$ gives $25$. Adding to $B$ will shift the new point right on top of $C$.

[image: Image of coordinate plane]

Above, $K$ is the rotated version of $A-B$.

Comment: To be more exact, it's not $131$ but $\|\langle38,125\rangle\| = \sqrt{17069} = 130.648\ldots$

Comment: @Théophile Thanks, updated, I just assumed his calculations were accurate in the diagram. I suppose the hypotenuse hinted that they were not.

Comment: hmm so i need to find the angle that this triangle is turned on had it been parallel? what are the missing points? x, y?

Comment: @AdanRamirez Calculate the value above. $<\frac{25}{\sqrt{17069}}\cdot 125 + 11406,\frac{25}{\sqrt{17069}}\cdot -38 + 1576>$

Comment: i dont mean to be rude, it's not that your explanation was not simple, im just dumb, too dumb to understand, can you link me resources that will help me understand your explanation? ex: 'point B would be at if A was the origin' need help with that, '<x, y> --> <y, --x> rotates a point 90 clockwise' i dont get any of this but im willing to learn

Comment: @AdanRamirez I had noticed that you were inexperienced in coordinate geometry so I started to make diagrams to help the explanation. They take time, however, to create.

Comment: @Nicholas Pipitone okay this diagram is inaccurate, what is the hypotenuse if i have 131 as the leg and 25 as adjacent? how do i calculate hypotenuse?

Comment: @AdanRamirez Move the conversation to chat if you wish to ask more questions. Also, note the significant difference between "dumb" and "inexperienced". If you are "willing to learn", that usually contradicts the former word.